# LWJGL Basics: Drawing Quads At Depth

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have this code that I understand now:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Main {

    public void start() {
        try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // init OpenGL
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 0, 800);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        // Clear the screen and depth buffer
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

        // set the color of the quad (R,G,B,A)
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

        // draw quad
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+200,100);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+200,100+200);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100,100+200);
        GL11.glEnd();

        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Main quadExample = new Main();
        quadExample.start();
    }
}
```

I want to know how to draw the box so that it is not drawn on the screen, but setback a bit, how?

Answer (score 1):

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3f(100,100,-100);
GL11.glVertex3f(100+200,100,-100);
GL11.glVertex3f(100+200,100+200,-100);
GL11.glVertex3f(100,100+200,-100);
GL11.glEnd();
```

Though that won't make any visual difference with a single quad in ortho.  You'll have to switch to a perspective projection matrix for it to look like it's "moved back".

Comment: Sorry about that, got the sign wrong on the Z coordinate.  Fixed.